# jquery datepicker + Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a question regarding the jquerydatepicker and the TextBoxFor() method.
I have an asp.net form in which I use them to create and edit an object. I use the same form for editing and creating.
It looks like this:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
     $("#datepicker2").datepicker(
     {
        dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd'
     });                        
   });
</script>

<div class=demo><%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Distribution.ToDate, new { id = "datepicker2", type = "text" })%></div>
```

It works fine, but my question is, how do I format the date when I use edit? For create it's okay, because it will display an empty textbox and if I select a date, it will be in the correct format. In edit, it first displays the whole datetime value, and it I select a date, it displays that one the way I want. But how do I do it, so that it will display it the way I want it from the beginning?

I tried to do it like so:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Distribution.ToDate.ToShortDateString(), new { id = "datepicker2", type = "text" })%>
```

but it gives an error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#startDatePicker').datepicker({ clickInput: true });
   });
</script> 


<% var attributes = (new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Value", Model.Plan.StartDate.ToShortStrin() } }); %>
<% attributes.Add("style", "width:80px; text-align:right"); %>
<% attributes.Add("ID", "startDatePicker"); %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Plan.StartDate, attributes)%>
```